# Access external network from container based service

Tags: docker, networking, containers

I have been searching a bit, but I think I am using the wrong terminology or something as what I am after does not seem like a special case.  We are in the process of looking how we can move our system from a bunch of windows/Linux based services into a container-based infrastructure.  Most of these services interface with some feed of data that is on another network.  I have been looking at the different container networks available both with Windows and Linux and am having a hard time finding the proper path to go about having a process that is running in a container be able to access some external data feed someplace out on a network that is not the container based network.  The closest thing I have found is using a host network on Linux which will put me on the host network, but am not seeing much support for that on the windows side.  I would like to be able to use the container network, but be able to route outside that network as well.  This seems like a valid use case, so I was wondering if anyone could point me in a general direction of how to go about accomplishing this.

Comment: Hey Rob, I am not 100% sure I understand your case entirely, but docker containers usually do not have problems accessing external networks/resources (and being accessed by them), as the requests are being masqueraded as they leave the host machine towards said external networks or resources. This is done automagically by the iptables rules that come with docker.

Comment: @jabbson I will retest again.  Perhaps I have been doing something wrong.  That would explain the lack of questions regarding this.  Thanks for the comment,

Comment: The heart of your question lies in the sentence: "having a process that is running in a container be able to access some external data feed someplace out on a network that is not the container based network."

The simplest method is probably exposing the service running on the host to the container which needs to talk to that host-service. This can be done with an Env-variable in the container, the value being the url of the service on the host.

Comment: You can quickly test if there's something in your setup that prevents containers from making external connections by running something like `docker run --rm curlimages/curl https://www.google.com/` which will do a `curl` request against a url of your choice.